# How to add logging.AddEventSourceLogger() in F#

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to do an Azure .NET Profiler Trace on my .NET Core 2.1.1 web app.

Azure provides the following instructions on how to do this:

> Ensure that you have the below code in your app's Program.cs as
> mentioned in Logging in ASP.NET Core article.
>
> logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
>
> Update the default LogLevel in appsettings.json to Information, like
> below
>
> "Logging": {
> LogLevel": {
> Default": "Information"
> }
> }

However, there are no instructions for F#.

How can I add `logging.AddEventSourceLogger();` to my Program.fs file?

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

module Program =
let exitCode = 0

let CreateWebHostBuilder args =
    WebHost
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()

    exitCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event source logger in `ConfigureLogging` extension method of `IWebHostBuilder`:

```
let CreateWebHostBuilder args =
    WebHost
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(fun logging ->
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger() |> ignore
        )
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```